# Best practice of converting an abstract base class to a derived one?

Tags: c++, pointers, derived-class

I have been working on a [PHP Bencode extension](https://github.com/Frederick888/php-bencode) recently and I'm storing a series of pointers of an abstract base class (`BItem`) in a `vector` or an `ordered_map` when dealing with the dictionary or the list in Bencode.

However, I need to convert the pointers back to the derived classes (`BDict`, `BList`, `BStr` and `BInt`) before I wrap and return them to PHP. So I defined a method called `getType()` and map the base class pointers to derived class ones according to the return value of the method.

But the map was used so often that after I had finished the initial version, the same if-else statements could be found everywhere in my code, like:

```
if (iter->second->getType() == "BDict") {
    BDict *current = new BDict(iter->second);
    retval += current->__toString().stringValue();
} else if (iter->second->getType() == "BList") {
    BList *current = new BList(iter->second);
    retval += current->__toString().stringValue();
} else if (iter->second->getType() == "BStr") {
    BStr *current = new BStr(iter->second);
    retval += current->__toString().stringValue();
} else if (iter->second->getType() == "BInt") {
    BInt *current = new BInt(iter->second);
    retval += current->__toString().stringValue();
}
```

This is awful. Honestly, I'm not very good at C++ but I've considered a lot. Converting the pointers with a template function like `template<typename T> T* toChild(BItem *parent)`? No, the compiler won't be able to determine the return type. Setting a "me pointer" and return it with a specific method? No, I can't override a function in the base class with one having a different return type.

So how can I implement this in a more elegant way?

Comment: Add a virtual function which each derived class overrides to wrap itself?

Comment: The Visitor pattern is the classic way to solve this if you have lots of methods that need to handle each type differently.

Comment: You are not merely "converting". You are creating new instances of `BDict` et al, and then promptly leaking them. `__toString` is a virtual method - just write `retval += iter->second->__toString().stringValue();`. Nothing in your code suggests you need `getType` at all.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: That looks like an _answer_ to me.

Comment: @AlanStokes Oh, you were right. And this is what I meant "me pointer". However, I tried this with a simple example with a completely different return type method in the derived class and the compiler gave me `conflicting return type specified` error. But actually for my case, it seems to be ok. Thanks very much.